# I am trying to get a public IP from an instance I am just starting up

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to go from spinning up a server using the AWS CLI then to `ssh` into it all in one script. I can get as far as loading the instance id into a variable but I need to then reformat it to push it to AWS to then get the public IP.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

azid=`(hidden for obvious reasons)`
azpswd=`(hidden for obvious reasons)`
hostip=`curl http://icanhazip.com`
COUNTER=120

#make a file to hold json information
touch instance.txt

#login to azure requireing webpage (not needed on cloud9)
#az login -u $azid -p $azpswd

#make a key pair and add to a variable (only needed one time)
#mykey=`aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name MyKeyPair`

#open ports on security group only needed one time
#aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-################# --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $hostip/32
#aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-################# --protocol tcp --port 80 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
#aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-################# --protocol tcp --port 8080 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0
#aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id sg-################# --protocol tcp --port 32400 --cidr 0.0.0.0/0

#launch instance and add ouptut to variable 
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-024a64a6685d05041 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --security-group-ids sg-################# --subnet-id subnet-################# > instance.txt 

#pull instance id from instance.txt
inid=`grep "InstanceId" instance.txt`

#testing
echo $inid

#wait for vm to spin up
for ((i=COUNTER; i>=1; i--))
do sleep 1
    echo $i
done

#get public ip from instance id
inip=`aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids $inid | grep PublicIpAddress`

#test
echo $inip

#ssh into freshly spun up server
ssh -i 'MyKeyPair.pem' ubuntu@$inip
```

Pulling an Instance ID from the json file then reformatting it to work with `aws ec2 describe-instances` to then pull down the public ip once the server is spun up. Then after all that ssh into it and push a kickstart file so that the freshly spun up server will run plex in a docker.

Comment: I would recommend that you consider a pre-built AMI approach or an EC2 launch with userdata script approach or even Ansible (or equivalent) as better ways to bootstrap EC2 instances.

Comment: that is essentially what I need to create for my class I tried to do a userdata approach last time however i could not see if or where it errored out using that approach so i decided to ssh in then push the kickstart file so that I can see if and where it errored out this time

Comment: `myip=$(curl ifconfig.co)` -- otherwise, use `jq` to extract the public IP from the JSON document.

Comment: I need it to be self contained even the ssh and install needs to be part of the script so unfortunately the curl ifconfig wont help me as the public ip wont be generated until after the command is executed by aws so the fact that I need to run the command from anywhere in the world and still get the ip address to initiate the ssh means that wont work in this case

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to install software on an Amazon EC2 instance after it **starts up for the first time**, then you should **provide a script via User Data**.

See: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

The script will run as `root`. To debug the script, look in:

```
/var/log/cloud-init-output.log
```

This technique is used by all AWS users and is much more reliable than the method you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: that is how I ran it last lab however for debugging and peace of mind I would prefer to run it all in the one command so I can see and if need be pipe the output of the spin up, update, and install of everything and see for quick reference where the stoppage is happening